# append angular component on click

Tags: angular, angular-components

I want to add a component inside the div with class myBLock on click of a button

```
code:
<div class="myExample">
    <button (click)="addComponent()">
    </button>
</div>
<div class="myBlock">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you say a little more? you want to add a component inside the div with class `myBLock` on click of a button?

Comment: Exactly what I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add html:

html

```
<div class="myBlock" #block>
</div>
```

in component:

```
@ViewChild('block') block:ElementRef;

addComponent() {
  block.nativeElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div></div>');
}
```

If you want to add a component you need to do it dynamically:

https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: That's not gonna work buddy (That's not how you insert angular components dynamically)

Comment: @Dummy You're correct my bad.  I'm not 100% sure what he is asking so I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a component variable to true / false based on button click. Then based on the variable value, show/hide component.

```
<div>
  <button (click)='showMyBlock = !showMyBlock'>
  </button>
</div>

<another-component *ngIf='showMyBlock'>
</another-component>
```

Comment: this is not what i need.  because i want to append different component on click, depend on the client